# Magento 2 - Determine current transaction isolation level

Tags: php, mysql, magento, transactions

I would like to determine the currently set transaction isolation level in Magento 2.
I have searched and found this php code:

```
  $resource = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection');
  $connection = $resource->getConnection();
  $isolationLevel = $connection->query("SELECT @@transaction_isolation");
```

This returns a type OBJECT, and being new to Magento 2, I dont know how to retrieve the isolation level from this. I tried get_object_vars($isolationLevel ) to see the object methods or properties, but this didnt work.

Could someone help with this issue please?